# How can I access to documents's random id to attach it include documents's fields?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLLk0.png)

I have a `RecyclerView` displaying a lot of photos from differed subcollection. I just want when the user longclick can edit or delete, I have get photo's reference from Firesbase Storage and attached uid on it. So if uid on the document == current user uid 
he could delete or edit .
the problem is i cant reach photo's path as it's fetched from different subcollection!! 
can you help me,please?

> Kotlin

```
class ViewHolder(view: View, var my_data: Data? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(view.context, More::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("description", my_data?.description)
                intent.putExtra("photo", my_data?.photo_uri)
                intent.putExtra("site", my_data?.site)
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }

            view.setOnLongClickListener {
                val popUp = PopupMenu(view.context, it)
                popUp.inflate(R.menu.edit_delete)
                popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.edit -> {
                            true
                        }
                        R.id.delete -> {

                            var dp: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                            dp.collection("Fraise")
                                    .document()
                                    .delete()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                                    }
                            Toast.makeText(view.context, "Note has been deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false  }
                popUp.show(); true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have kept your database structure from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158630/i-wanna-reach-every-single-uids-value-in-all-these-collection-there-is-a-way) where I provided you an answer and you are using a model class named `Fraise`, to delete/edit a photo from a particular user, please use the following code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val query = rootRef.collection("Fraise").whereEqualTo("uid", uid)
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in task.result) {
            val fraise = document.toObject(Fraise::class.java!!)
            fraise!!.setPhoto_url(new_photo_uri)
            rootRef.collection("Fraise").document(document.id).set(fraise)
        }
    }
})
```

If don't have a model class, you can make the update using a `Map` like this:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val query = rootRef.collection("Fraise").whereEqualTo("uid", uid)
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in task.result) {
            val new_photo_uri = HashMap<String, Any>()
            new_photo_uri["photo_uri"] = new_photo_uri
            rootRef.collection("Fraise").document(document.id).set(new_photo_uri, SetOptions.merge())
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi mariam! Did my answer helped you in any way?